# PHP user class.

Tags: php, oop, singleton

Hello guys I am writing my first PHP class and I would like to see what you guys think about this class. I am a bit new to it. 
So just like any other regular classes I normally create using Java, I created a static method where I instantiate my user class object then return it. I would like to use this class for new project. Is there a better way to do this or am I good design wise? Thanks

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Taban
 * Date: 8/21/15
 * Time: 1:55 PM
 */

class User
{
    private $userName;
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $emailAddress;


    public function __constructor()
    {
        $this->userName = null;
        $this->firstName = null;
        $this->lastName = null;
        $this->emailAddress = null;

    }

    public function setUserName($userName)
    {
        $this->userName = $userName;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->emailAddress;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->emailAddress = $email;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public static function userObject(){
        return new User();
    }


}
```

Comment: It should `public function __construct()`

Comment: I think this question better fits on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

A class that has both setters and getters is a sign of procedural programming disguised as OOP.

Remove the setters and pass the initialization values as arguments to the constructor:

```
/**
 * @param string $userName
 * @param string $firstName
 * @param string $lastName
 * @param string $emailAddress
 */
public function __constructor($userName, $firstName, $lastName, $emailAddress)
{
    $this->userName     = $userName;
    $this->firstName    = $firstName;
    $this->lastName     = $lastName;
    $this->emailAddress = $emailAddress;
}
```

Analyze the code that uses the getters and move it (as much as possible) into this class because this is where it belongs, then remove the getters.

If you didn't write any code that uses the getters then just remove them and resist the temptation to add them again.

When you discover you need a getter ask yourself if there is any good reason you handle the `User` properties outside the `User` class. Sometimes there is a reason (and you'll need to write the getter) but not always.

Example of code that belongs to a class:

```
class Product
{
    private $price;
    public function getPrice() { return $this->price; }
    public function setPrice($price) { $this->price = $price; }
}

$product = new Product();
// ...
// ...
$price = $product->getPrice();
$product->setPrice(0.8 * $price);     // apply 20% discount
```

It should be something like this:

```
class Product
{
    private $price;
    public function __construct($price) { $this->price = $price; }
    public function getPrice() { return $this->price; }
    public function adjustPrice($factor) { $this->price *= $factor; }
}

$product->adjustPrice(0.8);           // apply 20% discount
```

Observe how the code that used to need both the getter and the setter of the `$price` property was moved where it belongs, into the `Product` class. (method `adjustPrice()`).

Depending on the business model, probably it also needs a `setPrice()` method for `Product`, to change the price when there is no relationship between the old price and the new price but the correct way to adjust the price to apply a discount is coded in method `adjustPrice()`.

Also, the static instantiation method is an anti-pattern. The code that uses the static method is not testable in isolation.

Comment: Thanks @axiac. I already got that. But it is a good reminder because I am gonna be writing more PHP in the future for a new contract job hopefully :)